# Why is GORM performing cascading delete, even if I omit the belongsTo keyword?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following domain classes:

**Holiday**:

```
class Holiday {
    String justification
    User user
    //static belongsTo = User
        static constraints = {
        }
}
```

**User**:

```
class User {
    String login
    String password
    static hasMany = [ holidays : Holiday ]
        static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I have created a one-many relationships between `Holiday` and `User`. Note that I haven't included `belongsTo` on the `Holiday` class. Now I have written the following integration test:

```
void testWithoutBelongsTo() {       
        def user1 = new User(login:"anto", password:"secret")
        user1.save()
        def holiday1 = new Holiday(justification:"went to trip")
        holiday1.save()
        user1.addToHolidays(holiday1)
        assertEquals 1, User.get(user1.id).holidays.size()
        user1.delete()
        assertFalse User.exists(user1.id)
        assertFalse Holiday.exists(holiday1.id)
    }
```

Clearly in the above test case, I'm deleting only the `user1` instance, but when I run with assert statements I can see that GORM have implicitly deleted `holiday1`, too. And my Test cases have *PASSED*! How this can happen, even though I haven't given `belongsTo` keyword in `Holiday` class?

I'm using Grails version 1.3.7.

Comment: Just an advice: use simply Groovy's assert instead of JUnit assertEquals, it has better error reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`holiday1` was never saved as it does not validate: property `user` is neither set nor nullable.

Here is how your code in `Holiday.groovy` should look like:

```
class Holiday {
    String justification
    User user
    //static belongsTo = User
    static constraints = {
        user(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

And your test, with property `user` set properly in `holiday1`:

```
void testWithoutBelongsTo()
{
    def user1 = new User(login:"anto", password:"secret")
    user1.save(failOnError: true)
    def holiday1 = new Holiday(justification:"went to trip", 
                               user: user1) // Set user properly
    holiday1.save(failOnError: true)
    user1.addToHolidays(holiday1)
    assert 1, User.get(user1.id).holidays.size()
    holiday1.user = null  // Unset user as otherwise your DB
                          // won't be happy (foreign key missing)
    user1.delete()
    assert ! User.exists(user1.id)
    assert Holiday.exists(holiday1.id)
 }
```

In order to eliminate validation errors quickly in your tests, always use `save(failOnError: true)`. It will throw an exception if your object do not validate.

Comment: thanks for the advice on using groovy's `assert` keyword. Ya, it is throwing useful exception messages :D

Answer (score 0):

You should save holiday after adding it to the user.